# Python & JSON: ValueError: Unterminated string starting at:

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have read multiple StackOverflow articles on this and most of the top 10 Google results. Where my issue deviates is that I am using one script in python to create my JSON files. And the next script, run not 10 minutes later, can't read that very file.

Short version, I generate leads for my online business. I am attempting to learn python in order to have better analytics on these leads. I am scouring 2 years worth of leads with the intent being to retain the useful data and drop anything personal - email addresses, names, etc. - while also saving 30,000+ leads into a few dozen files for easy access.

So my first script opens every single individual lead file - 30,000+ - determines the date it was capture based on a timestamp in the file. Then it saves that lead to the appropriate key in dict. When all the data has been aggregated into this dict text files are written using json.dumps.

The dict's structure is:

```
addData['lead']['July_2013'] = { ... }
```

where the 'lead' key can be lead, partial, and a few others and the 'July_2013' key is obviously a date based key that can be any combination of the full month and 2013 or 2014 going back to 'February_2013'.

The full error is this:

```
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 9997847 (char 9997846)
```

But I've manually looked at the file and my IDE says there are only 76,655 chars in the file. So how did it get to 9997846?

The file that fails is the 8th to be read; the other 7 and all other files that come after it read in via json.loads just fine.

Python says there is in an unterminated string so I looked at the end of the JSON in the file that fails and it appears to be fine. I've seen some mention about newlines being \n in JSON but this string is all one line. I've seen mention of \ vs \ but in a quick look over the whole file I didn't see any . Other files do have \ and they read in fine. And, these files were all created by json.dumps.

I can't post the file because it still has personal info in it. Manually attempting to validate the JSON of a 76,000 char file isn't really viable.

Thoughts on how to debug this would be appreciated. In the mean time I am going to try to rebuild the files and see if this wasn't just a one off bug but that takes a while.

- Python 2.7 via Spyder & Anaconda
- Windows 7 Pro

--- Edit ---
Per request I am posting the Write Code here:

```
from p2p.basic import files as f
from p2p.adv import strTools as st
from p2p.basic import strTools as s

import os
import json
import copy
from datetime import datetime
import time


global leadDir
global archiveDir
global aggLeads


def aggregate_individual_lead_files():
    """

    """

    # Get the aggLead global and 
    global aggLeads

    # Get all the Files with a 'lead' extension & aggregate them
    exts = [
        'lead',
        'partial',
        'inp',
        'err',
        'nobuyer',
        'prospect',
        'sent'
    ]

    for srchExt in exts:
        agg = {}
        leads = f.recursiveGlob(leadDir, '*.cd.' + srchExt)
        print "There are {} {} files to process".format(len(leads), srchExt)

        for lead in leads:
            # Get the Base Filename
            fname = f.basename(lead)
            #uniqID = st.fetchBefore('.', fname)

            #print "File: ", lead

            # Get Lead Data
            leadData = json.loads(f.file_get_contents(lead))

            agg = agg_data(leadData, agg, fname)

        aggLeads[srchExt] = copy.deepcopy(agg)

        print "Aggregate Top Lvl Keys: ", aggLeads.keys()
        print "Aggregate Next Lvl Keys: "

        for key in aggLeads:
            print "{}: ".format(key)

            for arcDate in aggLeads[key].keys():
                print "{}: {}".format(arcDate, len(aggLeads[key][arcDate]))

        # raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")


def agg_data(leadData, agg, fname=None):
    """

    """
    #print "Lead: ", leadData

    # Get the timestamp of the lead
    try:
        ts = leadData['timeStamp']
        leadData.pop('timeStamp')
    except KeyError:
        return agg

    leadDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
    arcDate = leadDate.strftime("%B_%Y")

    #print "Archive Date: ", arcDate

    try:
        agg[arcDate][ts] = leadData
    except KeyError:
        agg[arcDate] = {}
        agg[arcDate][ts] = leadData
    except TypeError:
        print "Timestamp: ", ts
        print "Lead: ", leadData
        print "Archive Date: ", arcDate
        return agg

    """
    if fname is not None:
        archive_lead(fname, arcDate)
    """

    #print "File: {} added to {}".format(fname, arcDate)

    return agg


def archive_lead(fname, arcDate):
    # Archive Path
    newArcPath = archiveDir + arcDate + '//'

    if not os.path.exists(newArcPath):
        os.makedirs(newArcPath)

    # Move the file to the archive
    os.rename(leadDir + fname, newArcPath + fname)


def reformat_old_agg_data():
    """

    """

    # Get the aggLead global and 
    global aggLeads
    aggComplete = {}
    aggPartial = {}

    oldAggFiles = f.recursiveGlob(leadDir, '*.cd.agg')
    print "There are {} old aggregate files to process".format(len(oldAggFiles))

    for agg in oldAggFiles:
        tmp = json.loads(f.file_get_contents(agg))

        for uniqId in tmp:
            leadData = tmp[uniqId]

            if leadData['isPartial'] == True:
                aggPartial = agg_data(leadData, aggPartial)
            else:
                aggComplete = agg_data(leadData, aggComplete)

    arcData = dict(aggLeads['lead'].items() + aggComplete.items())
    aggLeads['lead'] = arcData

    arcData = dict(aggLeads['partial'].items() + aggPartial.items())
    aggLeads['partial'] = arcData    


def output_agg_files():
    for ext in aggLeads:
        for arcDate in aggLeads[ext]:
            arcFile = leadDir + arcDate + '.cd.' + ext + '.agg'

            if f.file_exists(arcFile):
                tmp = json.loads(f.file_get_contents(arcFile))
            else:
                tmp = {}

            arcData = dict(tmp.items() + aggLeads[ext][arcDate].items())

            f.file_put_contents(arcFile, json.dumps(arcData))


def main():
    global leadDir
    global archiveDir
    global aggLeads

    leadDir = 'D://Server Data//eagle805//emmetrics//forms//leads//'
    archiveDir = leadDir + 'archive//'
    aggLeads = {}


    # Aggregate all the old individual file
    aggregate_individual_lead_files()

    # Reformat the old aggregate files
    reformat_old_agg_data()

    # Write it all out to an aggregate file
    output_agg_files()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is the read code:

```
from p2p.basic import files as f
from p2p.adv import strTools as st
from p2p.basic import strTools as s

import os
import json
import copy
from datetime import datetime
import time


global leadDir
global fields
global fieldTimes
global versions


def parse_agg_file(aggFile):
    global leadDir
    global fields
    global fieldTimes

    try:
        tmp = json.loads(f.file_get_contents(aggFile))
    except ValueError:
        print "{} failed the JSON load".format(aggFile)
        return False

    print "Opening: ", aggFile

    for ts in tmp:
        try:
            tmpTs = float(ts)
        except:
            print "Timestamp: ", ts
            continue

        leadData = tmp[ts]

        for field in leadData:
            if field not in fields:
                fields[field] = []

            fields[field].append(float(ts))


def determine_form_versions():
    global fieldTimes
    global versions

    # Determine all the fields and their start and stop times
    times = []
    for field in fields:
        minTs = min(fields[field])
        fieldTimes[field] = [minTs, max(fields[field])]
        times.append(minTs)
        print 'Min ts: {}'.format(minTs)

    times = set(sorted(times))
    print "Times: ", times
    print "Fields: ", fieldTimes

    versions = {}
    for ts in times:
        d = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts)
        ver = d.strftime("%d_%B_%Y")

        print "Version: ", ver

        versions[ver] = []
        for field in fields:
            if ts in fields[field]:
                versions[ver].append(field)


def main():
    global leadDir
    global fields
    global fieldTimes

    leadDir = 'D://Server Data//eagle805//emmetrics//forms//leads//'
    fields = {}
    fieldTimes = {}

    aggFiles = f.glob(leadDir + '*.lead.agg')

    for aggFile in aggFiles:
        parse_agg_file(aggFile)

    determine_form_versions()

    print "Versions: ", versions




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You're going to need to show us your code.  If it has personal info, remove the info.

Comment: You really want me to post a JSON file with 76,000 chars in it? The code works for every other file but this. So I'm sure it has something to do with one of the fields that got saved. It contains the personal info of a couple thousand people. I could manually type the data into a new file almost as fast as I could remove that personal data from this one. And unless PHP or something can open this file the removal would have to be done manually. If no one can provide pointers without the full file then I'll delete the question.

Comment: No, I asked for you to show us your *code* — the Python, not the JSON.

Comment: Which part, the write or read? or both? There is no personal data in the code only in the data files.

Comment: p2p is my own package used to create python functions with the same names and inputs as PHP ones. It just makes picking up a new language much faster in my experience.

Comment: for anyone using colab facing the same issue, you can try to refresh the uploaded json file and rerun the loading code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So I figured it out... I post this answer just in case someone else makes the same error.

First, I found a work around but I wasn't sure why this worked. From my original code, here is my `file_get_contents` function:

```
def file_get_contents(fname):
    if s.stripos(fname, 'http://'):
        import urllib2
        return urllib2.urlopen(fname).read(maxUrlRead)
    else:
        return open(fname).read(maxFileRead)
```

I used it via:

```
tmp = json.loads(f.file_get_contents(aggFile))
```

This failed, over and over and over again. However, as I was attempting to get Python to at least give me the JSON string to put through a [JSON validator](http://jsonlint.com/) I came across mention of `json.load` vs `json.loads`. So I tried this instead:

```
a = open('D://Server Data//eagle805//emmetrics//forms//leads\July_2014.cd.lead.agg')
b = json.load(a)
```

While I haven't tested this output in my overall code this code chunk does in fact read in the file, decode the JSON, and will even display the data without crashing Spyder. The variable explorer in Spyder shows that b is a dict of size 1465 and that is exactly how many records it should have. The portion of the displayed text from the end of the dict all looks good. So overall I have a reasonably high level confidence that the data was parsed correctly.

When I wrote the `file_get_contents` function I saw several recommendations that I always provide a max number of bytes to read so as to prevent Python from hanging on a bad return. The value of `maxReadFile` was `1E7`. When I manually forced `maxReadFile` to be `1E9` everything worked fine. Turns out the file is just under 1.2E7 bytes. So the resulting string from reading the file was not the full string in the file and as a result was invalid JSON.

Normally I would think this is a bug but clearly when opening and reading a file you need to be able to read just a chunk at a time for memory management. So I got bit by my own shortsightedness with regards to the `maxReadFile` value. The error message was correct but sent me off on a wild goose chase.

Hopefully this could save someone else some time.

Comment: How to force `maxReadFile` to `1e9`?

Comment: @MutluSimsek maxReadFile is just a variable. So 'maxReadFile = 1E9'. This question is 7 years old and I haven't had to do this in a while. I apologize upfront if I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 21):

I got the same problem. As it turned out, the last line of the file was incomplete probably due to the abrupt halt of the download as I found there was enough data and simply stopped the process on the terminal.

Comment: Same here, apparently the data received from the API was sometimes incomplete.

Comment: In my case, the download (or file being used was still being downloaded) was not complete.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is here just like I am and if you're handling `json` from the form requests then check if there is any `Content-Length` header set or not. I was getting this error because of that header. I used the JSON beautification and found the json became quite large which raised this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while importing a json file that I've created, but when I import another json file It works even without changing anything in code. What I found different in the json file that I have created is that the content is on one line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeRhv.png)

The cause of having that shape is that I dumped the dictionnary while writing the file like this :

```
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
    json.dump(dictionnary, outfile)
```

But once I dumped the dictionnary alone then writing it :

```
json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent = 4) 

    with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile: 
        outfile.write(json_object)
```

I had the known and standard shape of json file :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTFUU.png)

So know using this json file and import it we'll not have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and apparently, the file was corrupted.
What helped me understand is to do

```
    with open("path/to/file", 'r') as f:
          raw_data = f.read()
```

And then I saw that the string ends abruptly.
Then, I took a smaller portion of the data after inspecting it.

```
index_of_the_end_of_last_record = 100 # For example
data = json.loads(raw_data[:index_of_the_end_of_last_record]+']')
```

I've added a - `]` because I had a list inside the json file.