# python json to csv json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 17177 (char 17176)

Tags: python, json, csv

1There are garbled characters in the json file, I want to ignore it,
I used the errors='ignore' parameter, but it still prompts errors

My json example：
{"network":"lin","id":null,"url":"lin.org/in/dirk-å­å¾·å-67172","username":"dirk-å­å¾·å-67172"}

```py
import csv
import json
import sys
import codecs


def trans(path):
    jsonData = codecs.open('‪C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.json', 'r', 
                   encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
    csvfile = open('‪C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8',
                   newline='', errors='ignore')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    flag = True
    for line in jsonData:
        dic = json.loads(line)
        if flag:
            keys = list(dic.keys())
            print(keys)
            writer.writerow(keys)
            flag = False
        writer.writerow(list(dic.values()))
    jsonData.close()
    csvfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = str(sys.argv[0])
    print(path)
    trans(path)
```

print

```py
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 17177 (char 17176)
```

Comment: Check this [link] maybe it helps (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541280/python-json-valueerror-unterminated-string-starting-at)

Comment: Can you share the complete traceback?